# How do you favorite a photo in Flickr when using the "New Photo Page" layout?

Tags: flickr

The information in the Flickr Help for Favorites is for the current design and states:

> We're only providing support for the normal site during the preview. Answers that you receive here (from staff & members) will relate to the current design not the preview. If you're having trouble with something that isn't covered in the FAQs you can opt out. If you have questions or feedback please let us know in the New Photo Page Preview Group.

So, has anyone figured out how to favorite a photo using the new-fangled preview page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button is still right above the image.

[image: Screenshot]

It's just as easy on the dark page.

[image: Another screenshot]

Comment: Wow. I'm not seeing that at all. Just the "Actions" and "Share this" are there.

Comment: Okay. I just realized my issue. There's no favorite button for your own images. Ha!